# Advance sorting with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

So i have input data just like bellow. I have 5 xslx tables. Within each xslx table are 5 columns. I want to join together xslx tables. So i did that with `pd.concat`. Problem occurs when i want to do some advanced sorting on that big joint together table. Bellow I tried to explain what i want to do so please check.

Input data:

```
  col1 col2
0  X    X
1  Y    Z
2  Z    A
4  A
5  B
```

I would like it to be sort like:

Output data:

```
  col1 col2
0  X    X
1  Y    
2  Z    Z
4  A    A
5  B
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need sorting? This rather looks like a mask ([`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) + [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)):

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].where(df['col1'].isin(df['col2']), '')
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2
0    X    X
1    Y     
2    Z    Z
4    A    A
5    B
```

Or maybe a left-[`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df[['col1']].merge(df[['col2']], left_on='col1', right_on='col2', how='left')
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2
0    X    X
1    Y  NaN
2    Z    Z
3    A    A
4    B  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
df.set_index('col1').join(df[['col2']].set_index('col2')).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2
0    A  NaN
1    B  NaN
2    X    X
3    Y    Z
4    Z    A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by looping through each row in your DataFrame and checking if the value in col1 is in col2. If it is, you can set the value of col2 to the value of col1 for that row. If not, you can set the value of col2 to an empty string for that row.

```
import pandas as pd

# assuming df is your DataFrame

# iterate over each row
for i in range(len(df)):
    # if value in col1 is in col2
    if df.loc[i, 'col1'] in df['col2'].values:
        # set col2 value to col1 value
        df.loc[i, 'col2'] = df.loc[i, 'col1']
    else:
        # set col2 value to an empty string
        df.loc[i, 'col2'] = ''

print(df)
```